# Dynamically create <form runat="server">

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, dynamic

How can I create a `<form runat="server" />` with code (c#)? My problem is that I want to have multiple forms on my page (and none initially). I'm loading all components from db.

I've looked everywhere and can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I solved it using this inside my Page:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
{
}
```

And then render my form with plain text.. Can't see any errors yet, but will update if any turns up.

Also, as I said in my question, I'm loading all control dynamically and I don't use any code behind with the controls (if I did, I guess some errors would turn up). All my post are handled by checking against HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.

Comment: If you are handling your own input and output, I really think you'll love MVC, compared to the constraints of webforms

Comment: Yeah, I do love .NET MVC. The problem is that this system was build before .NET MVC was released. I would love to use MVC instead of this crap ;)

Answer (score 1):

From painful memory, working with multiple forms in ASP.NET-webforms is a real pain. Maybe consider looking at ASP.NET-MVC which is much closer to the HTML; consequetly you can do anything you like re forms; just use a foreach in the view, writing a form for each item.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET page can have only one "server side" form.. that's one of the "core" rules.

So you'll have to find other way to achieve what you need.

You can work with UpdatePanels and "submitting" specific panel should send only its contents, ignoring the other data in the form.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET only allows for one serverside form but allows multiple *regular* forms in one page. I suggest you read this article: [**ASP.NET Forms**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163736.aspx).